# Keep getting error while installing new software for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

I keep getting this message while installing ADT for my eclipse helios

[image]

Comment: can't post it cuz i don't have the reputation

Comment: @ReazurRahman post a link to the image.

Comment: let me see if i can create a link for it

Comment: anybody know of a site that let you create URL for image on your desktop

Comment: my computer wont let me install adt unless i run it as administrator, if that helps any

Comment: actually here you go: http://i45.tinypic.com/cjkap.png

Comment: I have juno installed in my computer also but that came with the adt bundle i just want to configure it for my other eclipse and i keep getting that message in the middle of installation this is the link i am using: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Ensure that Java, Eclipse and the ATD are in a path without blanks, e.g. "Program Files"

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported before with an Eclipse Helios run by a JDK7:

- "[Failure to install ADT plugin to Eclipse - 'violates contract' error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221267/failure-to-install-adt-plugin-to-eclipse-violates-contract-error-message)"
- "[Install trouble for Android SDK in Eclipse Helios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12825776/6309)"
- "[eclipse 3.7.1 update error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544379/eclipse-3-7-1-update-error)"

The workaround seems still to be:

> Add the following line to your `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
```

And then relaunch Eclipse.

---

The other solution, even easier, is to update Eclipse to Juno

Comment: I also think its a problem with helios I just tried it on Juno and it worked Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @ReazurRahman Excellent. I have added the update option to the answer for more visibility.